# invalid zcash address while rawtransaction

Tags: blockchain, zcash

I am looking to perform raw transaction between t-address and z-addresses of zcash 
I have tried the following things

- when i use `createrawtransaction` it is throwing "invalid zcash address"
- error

> ~/zcash$ ./src/zcash-cli createrawtransaction
>   '[{"txid":"f7e04b684ee10c3c8e7aacdcd11454e7f21d91c5a8b27ae6cbbbca93efa57ddd","vout":0}]'
>   '{"ztJTQ72v68ZddM4vmJg77K1mdBXHWQPS8GXN4Yb7A8e48JUo3tNzLgej1yqFPFeNkVUL1CMeg62qHMr7joaYK35A86neMNM":7,"tmNHNUV56LiEyb8cSrrAgupHXnrxhbN1H6v":2.9999}'
>   error code: -5 error message: Invalid Zcash address:
>   ztJTQ72v68ZddM4vmJg77K1mdBXHWQPS8GXN4Yb7A8e48JUo3tNzLgej1yqFPFeNkVUL1CMeg62qHMr7joaYK35A86neMNM

Answer (score 0):

In the RPC call above :
the address format you are using `ztJTQ72v68ZddM4vmJg77K1mdBXHWQPS8GXN4Yb7A8e48JUo3tNzLgej1yqFPFeNkVUL1CMeg62qHMr7joaYK35A86neMNM` is not in the acceptable format, please use an acceptable encoded format public address.
Your second parameter `tmNHNUV56LiEyb8cSrrAgupHXnrxhbN1H6v` is the correct format used while calling this RPC method.
Rest all looks good.